# extract content from html page

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I'm trying to extract the content inside div tag with *id* `job_title1` in a html page. I'm using `htmlagilitypack` to fetch the data. Here is my code

```
        var obj = new HtmlWeb();
        var document = obj.Load("url of website ");

        var bold = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='job_title1']");

        foreach (var i in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='job_title1']"))
        {
            Response.Write(i.InnerHtml);
        }
```

When i tried to run this code i'm getting error at foreach saying the Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Please help me solving this.

Comment: Q: What language is this?  Your tag says C# ... but ...

Comment: ANS : @paulsm4 : looking pure c#  :)

Comment: He is using C#, C# 4.0 supports deferred type.  I personally never like that except for complex linq results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check `if null` like this:

```
var nodes = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='job_title1']");

if(nodes != null)
    foreach (var i in document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class='job_title1']"
    ...
```

**Edit**: Use `\"` instead `'`:

```
var obj = new HtmlWeb();
var document = obj.Load("url of website ");

var bold = document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@class=\"job_title1\"]");

if(bold!= null)
    foreach (var i in bold)
    {
        Response.Write(i.InnerHtml);
    }
```

Comment: Yes, the nodes is null. I'm new to this, so please tell me why the values are not fetched inside nodes. How to get the values inside that div tag.

Comment: Can you add a sample of your HTML?

Comment: I want the div tag content of the below html. 
<div class="job_title1"><span class="txt_green">MS CRM 4.0, MS CRM 2011, PHP, SQl server, My SQL, SSRS</span><br/>
              <br/>
              MCA (Computers), Amity Business School<br/>
              <br/>
              <span class="txt_grey">Last Active: 15th Jun 2012<br/>Resume ID: 23961482</span></div><div class="company_info1"><span class="bold">s3infotech</span> <br/>

       Annual Salary: 2.40 lacs<br/>
       Exp: 2Years <br/>
       <span >Preferred Location: Anywhere</span><br/>
       </div>

Comment: Sorry for troubling you, I'm trying to get the content of monster job portal webpage after login. I'm copying that url and using it. When i click on that link its asking for username and password. Can you please tell me how to pass the credentials so that the search result page only will open when i copy the search result url from browser and use it in code.

Answer (score 1):

You said "div tag with **id** job_title1", shouldn't the xpath be:

```
document.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='job_title1']")
```